# why does a print() affect how com1 is read?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I'm writing an interface for an old piece of electronic equipment that uses RS232 serial.  I've run into a problem that I can't seem to solve.  Here is the original code

```
def readMyPort():
    global readPort
    while True:   #always loop
        if readPort: # only do something of the port is active
            dataString = b''
            while (mySerialPort.inWaiting()>0):
                data = mySerialPort.read(1)
                if (data == b'') or (data == b'\r') or (data == b'\n'):
                    if (dataString != b''):
                        myOutput.insert('1.0', (dataString + b'\n').decode())
                        dataString = b''
                else:
                    dataString += data
```

The problem I face is that the instrument sends a string of 12 characters in response to a command, and I only seem to catch the last 4, and no, there are no '', '\r', or '\n' in the string.  In an effort to troubleshoot I added a print(), as shown below.  Magically I started to get all the data.

```
def readMyPort():
    global readPort
    while True:   #always loop
        if readPort: # only do something of the port is active
            dataString = b''
            while (mySerialPort.inWaiting()>0):
                data = mySerialPort.read(1)
                print(data)   #<-------- the added line
                if (data == b'') or (data == b'\r') or (data == b'\n'):
                    if (dataString != b''):
                        myOutput.insert('1.0', (dataString + b'\n').decode())
                        dataString = b''
                else:
                    dataString += data
```

Now I don't want to have all that printing going on normally.  I tried just adding a `print('')` and that works as well, but I still have all those \n getting printed.  I tried `print('', end = '\r')` but that didn't work.  Does anyone have an idea why?  I don't think it is a speed issue. I'm only running 9600 baud.  FYI: python 3.2 on a Win32 machine.  This routine is launched in it's own thread.

Answer (score 0):

The operation `print(data)` requires some time (relatively large) to print something to the console. So by adding the line `print(data)` you just add some delay inside your loop. You may verify this theory by substituting `print(data)` for `time.sleep(0.1 or whatever small value)` and checking that the problem is hopefully gone.

I think that the delay helps because without it `mySerialPort.inWaiting()` may becomes `0` sometimes (receive buffer is empty) **before** the transaction is actually completed. Your instrument can't simply output data that fast. In your final version of the code you may add `time.sleep()` instead of `print(data)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did try adding a delay before, but perhaps I didn't give it enough time.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer of Konstantin, it appears that the serial port needs some time to adjust the buffer and counters, so adding a small delay in the loop solved my problem.  1 ms is not enough but 10 ms is.  The final code is:

```
def readMyPort():
    global readPort
    while True:   #always loop
        if readPort: # only do something if the port is active
            dataString = b''
            while (mySerialPort.inWaiting()>0):  #if something is in the buffer
                data = mySerialPort.read(1)
                if (data == b'') or (data == b'\r') or (data == b'\n'):
                    if (dataString != b''):  #don't output empty strings
                        myOutput.insert('1.0', (dataString + b'\n').decode())
                        dataString = b''
                else:
                    dataString += data
                    time.sleep(0.01)   #slow the loop down a bit
```

I do continue to wonder if there is a more elegant solution.